# GMAIL rss don't see tag description.How to see Request headers of my iis 5 website

Tags: iis, rss, gmail, iis-logs

217.76.185.140/18.rss   asp.net server
If i add to webclip (gmail) rss http://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.rss it works fine
(See up of the inbox there are rss feed)
But my own rss feed don't see description tag.
1.I want copy request header (that send gmail to my iis server)
HTTP 101. etc
content-type

2.Than i want copy it and send this httrrequest with fiddler to http://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.rss
3.Than i will saw http response from quotebr.rss
4. I copy this resopnse and replace description,title etc to my own

1.I want to know how i can safe(log, trace request to iis 5 windows xp) fiddler don't saw it
2. How to see request from gmail to my site 3.Do y have rss samle,wich work in gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler won't see GMail's request for the feed, as the request will go directly from GMail server to your server, without ever touching the client computer. You'll have to log the request at your server.

```
[your computer]-------[gmail.com]------[your server w/ RSS feed]
```

1. your computer requests a page from gmail
2. gmail requests a page from your server (on completely different connection)
3. your server returns a response to gmail
4. gmail assembles the response into its own response
5. gmail returns the response to your computer

In Fiddler, you can only see steps 1 and 5, as they generate traffic between your computer and some other computer on the Net.